# Is there any way to show selected date from datepicker in kendo inside its footer?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

As we know datepicker footer show current date. I want to show the selected date inside it after selection.

I have tried footer and footer id to render the footer and change event but i was not able to modify the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manualy update footer inside change event

```
     $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
         change: function (e){$('#footer').text( kendo.toString(this.value(), 'D'))},
         footer: '<span id="footer">#:kendo.toString(data, "d")#<span>'
      });
```

Try it in dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/OBojiBEc

Comment: It is new form me to add attribute like the way you did in footer. Can you describe it more or tell me resource to read more about it?